# Connecting to a voice channel and sending audio in Discord.net

Tags: c#, audio, discord.net

After looking for hours I still can't find how should I set up sending an audio using Discord.net 1.0. All of the solutions I encountered have been for pre-1.0 relases and as far as I can see, new API is completly different.

So my question is: How do i join voice channel and send music through? Do I need external libraries (NAudio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is looking for Audio example it's [here](https://gist.github.com/Joe4evr/773d3ce6cc10dbea6924d59bbfa3c62a). You also need opus and libsodium in bot running directory. You can get this libraries on Discord "Discord API" sever with command ?tag voice-natives.