# How to play music from a local file

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

After a long run and trial I managed to connect my bot to a voice channel and disconnect from one as well. However I couldn't find a proper way to play music. I researched and tried to read and came across many different options like `ffmpeg`, `sharplink` and `lavalink` but I don't know how to use them.

There is an exact question on SO [How to Play Audio File Into Channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580798/how-to-play-audio-file-into-channel) but it talks in reference with JavaScript and not .NET so I am nowhere.

So, how to play audio (local file) from my bot in a voice channel after having it successfully connected.
Version : Discord.Net 2.x nightly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to a voice channel and sending audio in Discord.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380658/connecting-to-a-voice-channel-and-sending-audio-in-discord-net)

Comment: Thanks @linuxrocks but that is outdated and uses 1.x. I am using 2.x nightly and it doesnt work anymore. I already tried that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the audio stream itself, I'll give you an example using `ffmpeg` because that's what I used and it works.

**Full disclosure, the project I'm about to give samples of is my own.**

Right, so you already have the voice channel connect/disconnect stuff done, nice work!
Now all you're missing is streaming some audio (from a local file as your question indicates).

What you need to do is start a separate process for `ffmpeg`, using something like this:

```
private Process CreateStream(string filePath)
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{filePath}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    });
}
```

Note: `ffmpeg.exe` should be located in your project's root directory, otherwise just specify a different route in the `FileName = ""` param.

**Edit:** You also need to specify it to be copied to your output folder once the project is built. Adding these lines into your `.csproj` file should do the trick:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="ffmpeg.exe">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

To send the audio to the voice channel you're connected to, use something like this:

```
using (Stream output = CreateStream(filePath).StandardOutput.BaseStream)
using (AudioOutStream stream = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Music))
{
    try
    {
        await output.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         _logger.LogError(e, "Stopped audio stream");
    }
}
```

Where `client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Music)` is the `IAudioClient` your bot is connected to.

Ideally you would have some type of `AudioService` class to do all of this instead of the module responsible to executing the commands.

Here's an example of a module with a dedicated service, from where the code above was copied:

[Module](https://github.com/TheKrystalShip/Inquisition/blob/master/Inquisition.Core.Modules/AudioModule.cs) & 
[Service](https://github.com/TheKrystalShip/Inquisition/blob/master/Inquisition.Services/AudioService.cs)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: PS: that same code can be used to play audio from other sources, not only local files, so by passing a audio source URL into the ffmpeg process, you'll get audio playback. Here's an example URL: https://radio.truckers.fm, that's a direct audio stream source, so ffmpeg eats it up no problem. However it does not work for youtube videos, there's an extra step to achieve that.

Comment: Splendid. Though I managed to use the first approach and it worked finally I also tried the second approach. One question: Do I need to `.AddSingleton(AudioService)` in the `program.cs`? Also I appreciate your effort and will to disclose everything :)

Comment: Ideally yes, you would want to inject the `AudioService` into the `AudioModule` using `.AddSingleton<AudioService>()`. Also I forgot to mention one other thing, you'll need to copy `ffmpeg.exe` to your project's output, I'll edit my answer to include that.